# Better having more db or more table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Got a question.

Before my question, i wanted to add for tags something like db-optimization but the tags does not exist.

I actually have my db with a lot of table, im writing a program that do a little about Enterprise solution, i have an "alpha" system that can be seen by programmers, a "beta" system seen by programmer and some users and production system.

Now, i've got a lot of table (not all) like those:

- Table
- Table_beta
- Table_alpha

I know i can instead put all the beta and alpha tables in their own databases (i can create the one i need), and change all relations need.

I already know the mysql db limit on size of single table and eventually on database file itself (if not splitted).
I also know that separating them can help a little the performance of operations.

What do you think? Which solution is better? Actual one or db separating one?

As for some reference the application is a web-game and will store let's says from 120MB to 200MB for game system and near 5MB minimum for each player.

Thanks in advance for your reply's.

Answer (score 2):

If you are counting in the megabytes, you are no where near the limits on modern systems or databases. These have no bearing on your solution.

You should encapsulate your application in a single database, geared toward the production system. You should then have copies of this database for development, testing, performance tuning, and other applications. You should not be mixing data from the online application in the other systems -- unless you intentionally copy it over using replication mechanisms or other intentional systems.

Comment: I do not use replication system, i allow editing creating an edit line on alpha system, after that the line goes to beta one, after approved (and tested) it will return to production system. Each system got it's configuration and db automatic operation will be done only when system is in state "maintenance"

Comment: This only to not have duplicated system and use the lesser resource possible, i've tried to think it that way before creating it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hard pressed to imagine an advantage to putting test tables into your production system.

Then in your code, when you open a table, you must be saying

```
if environment = "alpha" then
  table="foobar_alpha"
elseif environment = "beta" then
  table="foobar_beta"
else
  table=foobar"
endif
```

Or somewhat better

```
table="foobar" & environment
```

(I'm using VB for the example. Little difference if another language.)

Or worse, you have something more convoluted.

This seems like it's just opening you up to the possibility of a program error that results in writing test data to a production table, just because in one of the hundreds or thousands of places where you specify a table name, somebody forgets to write the code to get the right table name.

It also means that all your queries have to be "assembled" with table names filled in on the fly, instead of just having a static query string. If you use stored procedures, you'd have to have multiple copies of the stored procedures.

And more horrifying still, any time you update a table definition, you have to make the update 3 times. And if you make a mistake and it isn't exactly the same, you could find that code that works in test doesn't work when you go to production.

This seems to create so many problems, and I just don't see any advantages.

So no, create a production database, that just has the tables needed for production. Then copy this database to use for development and testing.